# error parsing facebook json feed in ios

Tags: objective-c, xcode, json

I'm querying a Facebook public JSON feed. I'm getting an error:

> -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9146b90 2012-07-11 10:32:25.536 iB Top 50[1789:16a03]

I'm trying to parse the tag "message" and "picture" for the object with

```
"id": "108448345915250_320180984741984"
```

Please help me.

Example JSON:

```
{
"data": [
  {
     "id": "108448345915250_320181064741976",
     "from": {
        "name": "Amitabh Bachchan",
        "category": "Actor/director",
        "id": "108448345915250"
     },
     "story": "Amitabh Bachchan edited his Website and Location.",
     "story_tags": {
        "0": [
           {
              "id": 108448345915250,
              "name": "Amitabh Bachchan",
              "offset": 0,
              "length": 16,
              "type": "page"
           }
        ]
     },
     "type": "status",
     "created_time": "2012-07-10T05:30:10+0000",
     "updated_time": "2012-07-10T05:30:10+0000",
     "comments": {
        "count": 0
     }
  },
  {
     "id": "108448345915250_320180984741984",
     "from": {
        "name": "Amitabh Bachchan",
        "category": "Actor/director",
        "id": "108448345915250"
     },
     "message": "Singing in the praises of this new venture \u2026 metal mike and all \u2026",
     "picture": "http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/293763_320180974741985_675837103_s.jpg",
     "link": "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=320180974741985&set=a.126948684065216.26767.108448345915250&type=1&relevant_count=1",
     "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif",
     "type": "photo",
     "object_id": "320180974741985",
     "created_time": "2012-07-10T05:29:34+0000",
     "updated_time": "2012-07-10T,
          "shares": {
        "count": 41
     },
     "likes": {
        "data": [
           {
              "name": "Amir Samy",
              "id": "100000377429168"
           },
           {
              "name": "Rashi Shrivastava",
              "id": "100001002346693"
           },
           {
              "name": "Satish Wakpaijan",
              "id": "100002129452923"
           },
           {
              "name": "Sushil Kumar",
              "id": "100002105808620"
           }
        ],
        "count": 300
     },
     "comments": {
        "count": 45
     }
  },
  ...
```

iOS Code:

```
jsonurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/TheAmitabhBachchan/posts?access_token=AcessToken"];

jsonData=[[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:jsonurl];

jsonArray = [jsonData objectFromJSONString]; 

items = [jsonArray objectForKey:@"data"];

story = [NSMutableArray array];
title = [NSMutableArray array];
picture = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSDictionary *item in items )
{
    [story addObject:[item objectForKey:@"message"]];
   /* [title addObject:[item objectForKey:@"name"]];
    [picture addObject:[item objectForKey:@"picture"]];*/
}
```

Comment: yup its of type nsdictonary..want i want is to parse the object "message" and object "picture".i m little desperate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line :

```
jsonArray = [jsonData objectFromJSONString];
```

you are fetching the object from the obtained JSON string. You have to convert theJSON string to its correct value. Use SBJSON parser for this.

It is not about that your jsonArray or item is a dictionary and your store the values in dictionary.Its about what does the following methods return :

```
[jsonData objectFromJSONString];
[item objectForKey:@"message"];
```

Are both(jsonArray and item) dictionaries? One of them is NSString as your error says.Parse the JSON value correctly.

Then check this :

```
NSString *sss = @"https://graph.facebook.com/TheAmitabhBachchan/posts?access_token=393411130717153%7C1HFhZAByEHp89q6CPECJTFzuzfg";
NSURL * jsonurl=[NSURL URLWithString:[sss stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: jsonurl];
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                                     options:kNilOptions 
                                                       error:nil];
NSArray *items = [json objectForKey:@"data"];
// NSDictionary *item = [items objectAtIndex:1];

NSMutableArray *story = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSDictionary *item in items )
{

    if([item objectForKey:@"message"] || [item objectForKey:@"message"] != nil || [[item objectForKey:@"message"] length]>0){
        [story addObject:[item objectForKey:@"message"]];
    }

}
```

Not each of your dictionary contains the key - "message".It is present in the second dictionary in the array.

Comment: If your jsonArray is a dictionary then what does your 'items' gives? NSLog to see if it is a dictionary? The error coming is saying that you are using the instance method 'objectForKey' over a NSString.This should be used for NSDictionary/NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: sorry not the 'items' check for 'item'.

Comment: both item and jsonArray are nsdictionary when i parse the object message i m getting a nil value

Comment: check my edited answer and use the accesstoken value instead of 'AccessToken' which in this case is '393411130717153%7C1HFhZAByEHp89q6CPECJTFzuzfg'

Comment: thnaks.could u help me get the array of messages..by any other means...i d be so greatful

Comment: thanks bro..u ve saved my day...could u explain me the logic u used above

Comment: I have checked for each dictionary if it contains the 'message' key or not.I only have added the 'message' if present in the dictionary accessed in the iteration.Its a simple check.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL * jsonurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/TheAmitabhBachchan/posts?access_token=AcessToken"];
 NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: jsonUrl];
 NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                                     options:kNilOptions 
                                                       error:nil];
NSDictionary *items = [json objectForKey:@"data"];
```

This must work. Now you can fetch objects from `items` dictionary.

Comment: cud u gimme an example with the above jsonstring

Comment: sure take all the time you need...:)

Comment: still getting error while parsing the object message...i ll give u my complete json string... https://graph.facebook.com/TheAmitabhBachchan/posts?access_token=393411130717153%7C1HFhZAByEHp89q6CPECJTFzuzfg

Comment: create NSError *err object and put its address as a parameter to [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data                                                   options:kNilOptions   error:&err]; and then check its description. it will tell what is the nature of the error

Comment: its the same above error NCFSString insertobject is nil...is it possible to check the above json url that i have given in your code and parse the message..will be greatful

Comment: the problem is with your NSString, particularly with access token. everything worked ok for me when i used this string @"https://graph.facebook.com/TheAmitabhBachchan/posts?access_token=393411130717153%7C1HFhZAByEHp89q6CPECJTFzuzfg"

Comment: is this the problem with the url:https://graph.facebook.com/TheAmitabhBachchan/posts?access_token=393411130717153%7C1HFhZAByEHp89q6CPECJTFzuzfg

Comment: check your AccessToken. it is probably wrong. to make sure just put the url itself without writing words "AccessToken" inside it and use actual access token "393411130717153%7C1HFhZAByEHp89q6CPECJTFzuzfg" and you'll see that it works all right

Comment: i was able to parse the object id...but not message...were could de problem be?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's a very BAD formatted json i have personally tested this

```
 NSURL *jsonurl1=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/TheAmitabhBachchan/posts?access_token=393411130717153%7C1HFhZAByEHp89q6CPECJTFzuzfg"];

NSString *jsonData=[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:jsonurl1];
NSDictionary *jsonArray = [jsonData objectFromJSONString]; 
NSLog(@"Js %@", [jsonArray objectForKey:@"data"]);

NSMutableArray *ar = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[ar addObject:[jsonArray objectForKey:@"data"]];

NSLog(@"AAAA %@", [[[ar objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"picture"]);
```

and the output is

**2012-07-11 13:20:41.987 InstagramDemp[4834:f803] AAAA http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/293763_320180974741985_675837103_s.jpg**